# How would (mostly the the head of) a hunting oriented mountain hominid look like?

Tags: biology, evolution

Say you have a near-human hominid that had more time to evolve than us, living on a mountain and using long-range weapons (bows, throwing spears, slings) to hunt mostly small really fast prey (birds, hares, etc). The rocky mountain makes sounds harder to pinpoint, prey is small, fast, and distant (and inaccessible if you run to them) and there is a lot of glare because of the sun. So I was wondering, mostly the skin, ears, and eyes, what would they look like? Would ear perhaps become a bit more mobile? Would they get a different pigmentation around the eyes to help with glare?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is a very broad and open ended questions asking us to brainstorm and generate ideas for you, with many valid answers. You're also asking a lot of sub questions. We prohibit overly broad, open ended, open ended questions. We similarly prohibit questions with many valid answers, or questions that ask us to brainstorm or generate ideas.

Comment: Vote to Close: (a) What things look like is an aesthetic. You can choose anything you want. There may be some terrestrial creatures that can be used to suggest ideas, but brainstorming isn't a good fit for this site (see the [help/on-topic]). In short, what things look like is off-topic storybuilding, not on-topic worldbuilding.  (b) You're asking us to design your entire creature for you. We don't do that. We'll help you with specific problems, but you're responsible for the overall design.

Comment: This question could be rephrased as "what are common (mammalian) adaptations for living in bright sunlight?" Or "how can I improve human sight (for distance and resolving distant objects)?" Or (a separate question) "how do I optimize humans for hunting agile prey?"

Comment: My intention is not to get free work, and I'm sorry if I phrased it poorly (English is not my native language), but I truly don't know where to start to do something even remotely naturalistic. I would not want the creature to become a chimera of different animals. Therefore Pipperchip answer seems to be the best and most amicable one; Any rephrasing of resource that would not require a degree in biology would be appreciated then. I apologize once more

Comment: This question is too broad for the Worldbuilding stack exchange. However, why do you think such a hominid would look significantly different from humans? We are a hunting oriented hominid species that has evolved to require a meat based diet.

Comment: I'm afraid PipperChip's suggestions wouldn't help. Please don't misunderstand us, we really do want to help. Consider: (a) "more time to evolve than us" doesn't really mean anything. We don't have an example of anything that has evolved more than us and it's not at all simple to look at, for example, the evolution from apes to humans and extrapolate that that would mean. Worse, something that's evolved longer than humans but aren't as technologically advanced than humans? Odd. (b) Creatures that use arrows need hands and fingers. Fast prey means good eyesight and binocular vision. (\*cont.\*)

Comment: (c) Tell us about the sun. "More glare" doesn't mean much and humans lived without sunglasses for a very long time before inventing them. (d) but in the end, skin color, ear shape, eye design... that's mostly window dressing, which is why it's off topic.

Comment: If they're near-human intelligence, why on earth don't they use traps and snares? If they had any sense they'd adapt their hunting technique to fit the prey, not expect the prey to hold still whilst they get impaled by ranged weapons.

Answer (score 2):

**Snub nosed monkey?**

[image: snub nosed monkeys]

(https://news.cgtn.com/news/189510-2/index.html)[The Yunnan Snub Nosed Monkey]

You must admit these monkeys have a good look, and one that has not been much used in fiction.  They are the primates that live at the highest altitude and so I conclude that some of their very distinctive features are adaptions to that lifestyle.

I cannot say I understand.  Lots of face fur makes sense to keep off the UV and no nose  - so it does not get frostbit?  One would think extra nose would help humidify dry air but these guys have gone the opposite direction.  And what about those big kissable lips?

Hmm.  In any case, your high altitude hunters are the descendants of snub nosed big-kissing mohawk-sporting snub nosed monkeys!